# Magento2 attribute default label issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes

when i want add more than 36 character I get below error on add attribute, default label section:

> Attribute code "attr_______________________________" is invalid.
>   Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this
>   field, first character should be a letter.

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you have attribute label more than 36 character,set attribute code manually not grater than 36 char.
[image]